# Call Using Whatsapp url scheme on iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift2, nsurl, whatsapp

We can open conversation/chat window for WhatsApp by using URL Scheme:

```
        if schemeAvailable("whatsapp://")
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?abid=68")!)//68 is the example, addressbook contact id
    }
    else
    {
        UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/app/whatsapp-messenger/id310633997")!)
    }
```

I want url scheme to start call? I not found any documentation or reference for it either on WhatsApp official page or on any blog.
Can we do this or its not possible?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Whatsapp doesn't have URL Scheme for Call feature.

But it does have custom URL scheme to chat with a specific contact.

You can keep checking more at : https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013.

Comment: How Addressbook doing direct calling on WhatsApp? Any Idea? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following url to directly open contact and use

> click to chat feature

on whatsapp to any contact number

```
UIApplication.sharedApplication().openURL(NSURL(string: "whatsapp://send?phone=15551234567")!)
```

see that also
https://faq.whatsapp.com/en/android/26000030/?category=5245251